# what is the approach to solve circular linked list?

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

Given a circular linked list, impplement an algorithm which returns node at the beginning of the loop.

DEFINITION:
Cicular Link list: A(corrupt) linked list in which a node's next pointer points to an earlier node, so as to make a loop in the linked list.

EXAMPLE:
Input: A->B->C->D->E->C[the same C as earlier]
Output: C

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? You will get help here but don't expect your homework to be done by SO users.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code that you've tried to apply to your question. In addition, please post any actual error message you've received, and what steps you've taken so far to research or resolve your programming issue.

Comment: I can find if there is no loop in the link list but if loop is present then loop goes on infinity.

Comment: I am getting confused, how to find starting point of loop, I think that is the tricky part where I stuck.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [tortoise and the hare algortihm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection):

1. Start with two pointers, call one the `tortoise` and the other the `hare`
2. At each time step, advance the tortoise once, and the hare twice
3. Repeat until they are equal

This gives you an element inside the loop. To find the beginning of the loop:

1. Advance the tortoise one step at a time, counting the number of steps
2. Stop until you reach the hare

This will allow you to find the length of the loop. Then you simply need to step `size-length` times to find the start, where `size` is the number of elements in your "linked-list".

This is also known as Floyd's cycle detection algorithm.

Comment: I don't think you are the the beginning necessarily when the two pointers are equal

Comment: Woops, got a little ahead of myself there. Edited.

Comment: Problem, you say `size` is the size of the list but when there is a cycle in the list, its size is infinite.

Comment: @Thomash: Size as in number of elements. Added clarification.

Comment: can you tell me how you calculate that pointer are `size-length` apart from where they meet last time?

Answer (score 1):

A common algorithm to *detect* a loop is to have two pointers/iterators advance through the list one advancing one element at a time, the other two.  If the two iterators ever point to the same element, there is a loop in the list.

Once you find the loop, you can collect all the elements in a set, then start from the beginning of the list until you find an element in that set.  This element can be considered as the "beginning" of the loop

Answer (score 1):

The simplest algorithm is to use a data-structure to store the already visited elements. You can use either a hash table(about O(n)) or a simple sorted array O(nlog(n)).

You can also assume that your linked list is a graph and use one of the common used algorithms for [cycle detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection).